# How can I insert text into another file [file_put_contents]

Tags: php, html, file-put-contents

I've been trying to use php's file management systems, but I can't figure out how to do one thing. I have a file that I am going to use as a template file. Basically I would copy the contents of the template file and save them as another file.

I tried to use file_put_contents to insert a string into the copied file, but rather than simply inserting the string somewhere in the copied file, it completely replaces the entire code with the string.

How could I put a string into a php file without erasing the already existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not specifying the `FILE_APPEND` flag when calling `file_put_contents`.

**Example:**

```
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND);
```

You can find the documentation here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!